# Rust traits required to get an algorithm to work with both f32 and f64 in Rust

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to write a generic linear interpolator that works on both `f32` and `f64`. My code is as follows:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct LinearInterpolation<Real>
{
    pub data: Vec<Real>,
    pub start_time: Real,
    pub time_step: Real,
}

use std::convert::From;

impl<Real> LinearInterpolation<Real>
    where Real: std::ops::Div<Output = Real> + std::ops::Sub<Output=Real> + std::cmp::PartialOrd + Default + Copy
{
    fn at(&self, time: Real) -> Real {
        let diff: Real = Real::from(time - self.start_time);
        if diff < default::Default() {
            panic!("This is really bad!");
        }
        let index = diff/self.time_step;
        let index = index.floor() as usize;
        if index - 1 >= self.data.len() {
            panic!("Index is too large!");
        }
        let y0 = self.data[index];
        let y1 = self.data[index+1];
        let slope = (y1 - y0)/self.time_step;
        y0 + slope*diff
    }
}
```

However, I cannot get the `index.floor()` method to work. The compiler error message is

```
error[E0599]: no method named `floor` found for type `Real` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:23:27
   |
23 |         let index = index.floor() as usize;
   |                           ^^^^^
```

What traits should I add to get any floating point type to work with this generic? and more generally, what traits are required so that a generic numerical function, which calls standard numerical functions like `log`, `sin`, and `exp` compiles successfully?